# In robotframework is it possible to define a set of keywords inside another keyword via api

Tags: api, robotframework

I want to create a main python file consisting of test suite , cases and keyword. I was able to create these. but  need to create a custom keyword consisting of multiple builtin keywords. But the code is not getting executed. any help would be appreciated :)

```
# file1.py
def main():
    suite = TestSuite('TS03_ContainerAcceptance')
    suite.resource.imports.library("BuiltIn")
    suite.resource.imports.library('CommonLibrary/CustomLibrary.py')
    suite.resource.imports.library('Selenium2Library')

    test = suite.tests.create(name='TS03_Create a container', tags=['Medium'])
    test.doc = "Create a container"
    test.keywords.create('Open Staging Server site and maximize', args=[rv.LOGIN_URL, rv.BROWSER], type='kw')

# CustomLibrary.py
@keyword('Open Staging Server site and maximize')
def open_staging_server_site_and_maximize(test, rv):
     test.keywords.create('Open Browser', args=[rv.URL, rv.BROWSER], type='kw')
     test.keywords.create('Maximize Browser Window', type='kw')
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by not getting executed - what is present in the log after a run, is there an error. In general, with these two statements - `kws = Keyword('Open...')` and `suite.keywords.append(kws)` it looks like you're defining the keyword in the suite with the same name, thus overriding the one imported from the resource file.

Comment: I mean, the browser is not getting open. Is there any example for how to make it work.